# Wordpress network site URL handling

Tags: wordpress

I have a szenario I don't know how to solve.
I have installed a MU Wordpress site.

**First problem - site path**

I have two sites "www.powerdoo.com" (site1) and "www.powerdoo.com/de-de" (site2). 
But I want that my main site also has default path, so the result should be "www.powerdoo.com/en-us" (site1).
Inside the network "sites" settings it is not possible to change the path for the main site.
How can i solve this?

**Second problem - web.config redirect**

It my first problem is solved I now want the URLs Redirect like this:

www.powerdoo.com -> www.powerdoo.com/en-us

www.powerdoo.de -> www.powerdoo.com/de-de

Can anybody help me how I have to write a rule for this?

Thanks Steffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to map the domains to the respective wp sites and have rewritten the base url.

This plugin will help you out to achieve those redirects, is extremely easy to set up and also it will take care of the base url rewrites.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

This way your sites will work fine with both URLs (www.powerdoo.com -> www.powerdoo.com/en-us) and most probably you won't need to mess up the theme's code.

> The only thing you need to be aware of is that "if it gets to happen"
>   that on some places of your theme the base url rewrite doesn't work it
>   will be most probably due to the way the original url is generated by
>   WP engine inside of the theme. But if you are php handy you will be
>   able to fix it on the theme or the child-theme with a
>   ***str_replace();***.